# Writing an OS; asm keyword troubles

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att, osdev

```
asm("lidt (%0)" : : "p"(&idtr));
```

The above statement will be used to define an IDTR in my IA-32 operating system. For some reason though, the compiler chokes on it:

```
kernel/kernel.c:52:2: error: invalid 'asm': invalid expression as operand
  asm("lidt (%0)" : : "p"(&idtr));
  ^
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? If you need any more context to answer my question, please say so and I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the instruction, you got every possible thing wrong.
The correct way:

```
asm("lidt %0" : : "m"(idtr));
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting `/tmp/ccfk5J0f.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccfk5J0f.s:293: Error: missing ')'
/tmp/ccfk5J0f.s:293: Error: junk \`(%esp))' after expression`.

Comment: Show how `idtr` is defined. This method works, it's even [used in the linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/pm.c#L98).

Comment: `IDTR idtr = (IDTR) {.size = sizeof(IDT), .offset = (uint32_t) &IDT};` where `IDT` is an array of IDT descriptors.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `()` and really just have `lidt %0`? I get exactly that error if I change it back to `lidt (%0)` which is **wrong**.

Comment: No, I didn't.  Duh :p

Comment: @mandatory-access-control: Do not use a _compound literal_ in an initialiser. It is only needed in a normal expression. And you should use the correct types when casting a pointer to an integer: `(u)intptr_t`.